# Duende Bff Timezone

Tags: asp.net-identity, backend, duende-identity-server, duende

I am currently using the BFF library from Duende and Server-side sessions. As I can store my session in my database, I see that the timestamp for the created session is not accurate, as it is not the correct timezone.

I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation about that. Do you know if there is a way to customize the timezone ?

Thank you in advance